# QT Remove Horizontal header of table

Tags: c++, qt

I have a function `setHorizontalHeader`,which adds a header to the table by adding header items one by one using `setHorizontalHeaderItem`.If I want to delete a header which function should I use?
Looks that `takeHorizontalHeaderItem`() suits, but it removes the item without deleting it.
After caling takeHorizontalHeaderItem for all items I get the header with numbers inside it.
I need to entirely delete the header (data + cells) – How do I implement it correctly?

Comment: Do you want to completely hide the header row?

Comment: @Mat Yes I want to hide it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`horizontalHeader`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#horizontalHeader) in a `QTableView` is a widget like any other. If you want to hide it, just call its  `hide()` member (which is a slot too).

```
 view->horizontalHeader()->hide();
```

This hides the whole header bar. It doesn't destroy or otherwise change the contained header items.

When you want the header to be displayed again, simply `show()` it. The header items will remain as they were before the `hide()` (unless you've changed them in between).

```
 view->horizontalHeader()->show();
```

(Works for the vertical header too, obviously.)

Comment: Should I use takeHorizontalHeaderItem before?

Comment: No. This operates on the whole header row, not on individual header items. You can leave the header items intact, they will simply not be displayed any more (and they'll show up again if you call `show()` on the header).

Comment: OK.What about if after some execution flow I will want to display headers (once more).Should I use some kind of "unhide"?

Comment: Look carefully at my previous comment, there's a very big hint in there :)